# Update of javafx listview to fewer elements

Tags: listview, user-interface, javafx, binding

So I'm using javafx ListView to represent some data in an application.
The content of the listviewis bound like so

```
ListView<String> listView = new ListView<String>();
Bindings.bindBidirectional(listView.itemsProperty(), new SimpleObjectProperty<>(navigationItem.getItems()));
```

That way, when **navigationItem.getItems()** contents changes, the content of the listView does too.

My problem is the following: if there was n items in the lists, they are correctly dispayed, but when updating to less than that (let's say m), the m first are correct, but the n-m last items are the previous ones and are not cleared.

I'm updating my lists like so:

```
mItems.clear();
mItems.addAll(pItems);
```

**mItems** is the list the is returned by **navigationItem.getItems()**.

One more thing, due to the way the ui is handled, I don't have access to the listview after initialization.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1: (This won't solve your problem, but might make your code simpler.) Do you really need this binding? Can't you just do `listView.setItems(navigationItems.getItems())`?. 2. This sounds like a problem with the list cell. Do you have a custom list cell implementation? If so, include it in your question.

Comment: Hey James, 
1) Good point, it make the code simpler.
2) Indeed, I had some old code that was sleeping at the bottom of my class... and that was now useless... Fixed everything, thanks a lot !

Comment: I'll mark this as duplicate, just because I think it might come up easily in searches and will point other users to the correct fix.